# Eclipse with WebLogic do not redeploy

Tags: eclipse-plugin, weblogic12c

after I make some editing to few source java files, the weblogic plugin seems to not re-deploy the application because it show me a older version of build.

I've tried to:

Add-remove resource from weblogic plugin
Clean and republish
Reinstall weblogic

Into bin directory I see that the .class are correctly updated!

Any suggestions?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Deleting all classes directory folder solved the problem!